# (Dis-)Advantages of "push-in" to expandable handlebar end plugs

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars

I just [discovered that my extension type handlebar plug was almost impossible to remove](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/55383/38253), at least without lasting damage/complete destruction. Until now I only ever encountered "push-in" plugs, which have a slightly bigger, but flexible part that holds the plug in place when pushed in. Currently the only difference I see is the former is potentially not removable, the latter is unproblematic in that respect. However there must be a reason for the existence of expandable plugs.

How do push-in plugs as handlebar end caps compare to expandable type ones, i.e. what are the respective advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: I hope I am not annoying anyone or disrespecting bicycle.SE standards with my questions. If I do, please let me know ;)

Comment: you questions fit community guidelines. Welcome to bicycles.stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

All the simple plastic bar end plugs I've ever used simply fell out at some point.

On a road bike drop bar I find it utterly impossible to tuck bar tape into the end of the bar and secure it with a simple plug.

There are better designs of expansion plug than the ones you had trouble with. In some expansion plugs the wedge is built into the cap. The bolt pulls the plug against the cap/wedge. When removing, pulling on the bolt does not tighten the plug.